# Deployed database to Azure using SSMS 2016 is not accessible inside web portal

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server, azure-security

I used Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2016 to deploy my database to Azure and everything went OK with no problem and it managed to create the database on Azure however the imported database is not visible outside the Azure SQL Server(Web portal) as a standalone resource and also when I try to access it within the Azure SQL server it complains : "Access denied".

[image]

What is the difference between this database and the one I create using web portal? If I create the database in web portal it will be visible as a standalone resource in the resource group but importing it from management studio only makes it only visible inside the sql management studio. 
Should I add any special permission from the management studio to this newly imported database to make it visible inside the web portal?

[image]

- **Update 1** : Just realised that this behaviour only happens when I choose UK South region. West-Europe databases can be created and accessed using both Web portal and SSMS with no problem.
- **Update 2** I tried creating the database in North Europe region and did not have any problem either. This issue needs to be resolved by the **UK-South region SQL Azure Team**.

Comment: Just tried what you did, everything works fine. The database is acessable in portal and shows up as an individule resource in my resource group. Did you config any specific settings for that database in SSMS, especially permission settings?

Comment: Looks like this is region specific?I don't have this problem with the databases in West-Europe region (I can create the database in SSMS and it appears as an individual resource with no problem) however the same database setup for the newly-available "UK South" region is not visible as an individual item. I get "Access denied" as I mentioned above.Can you try creating the database using SSMS in a UK-South region SQL server and check your database availability in web portal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been resolved now and the databases in UK South region can be happily deployed from SQL Server Management Studio and they are fully accessible in the web portal.

Answer (score 1):

you are correct, there was a configuration issue where for a period SQL Databases created in the Azure UK South or UK West regions via T-SQL (such as via SSMS), via the old portal, or via the older service management APIs or PowerShell may not have been visible in the Azure Management portal (portal.azure.com). Affected databases were online and fully accessible to applications throughout. The issue has now been resolved and impacted customers were notified. We are taking steps to improve the validation of configurations to prevent a recurrence of this. We apologize for the inconvenience.